# Excel Macro recording "Too many line continuations" error

Tags: excel, vba, filter, limit

I am writing a macro that, besides doing other things, should filter a long column of data that consists of positive and negative numbers. The numbers could be any value, and not necessarily all values between -4095 and 4095, but the entire column will vary in length up to over 800,000 rows. I want to filter out any number in the column that is -4095, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 4095.
 Doing this manually is easy using the filter option and unchecking the numbers I want left out, but recording it to a macro causes the error "Too many line continuations" after about 230 numbers. Obviously this is because the macro lists what numbers it leaves in the column, rather than those it removes. I know about the 25 physical lines limitation and that I should add more numbers to each line, but how can I do this without having to type in over 8100 different numbers - most four digits long, each in quotations with a comma in between each number? This would take me forever!
I know of other code methods to accomplish this process, but they can take over 45 minutes to complete on huge files. The Filter process is much faster, often finishing in about 30 seconds, even with large files. I have also tried other filtering Criteria, but nothing else seems to work.

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$4:$C$82784").AutoFilter Field := 1, Criteria1 := Array("0" _
    ,"-1","10","-10","100","-100","1000","-1000","1001","-1001","1002","-1002", _
    "1003","-1003","1004","-1004","1005","-1005","1006","-1006","1007","-1007", _
    "1008","-1008","1009","-1009","101","-101","1010","-1010","1011","-1011","1012" _
    ,"-1012","1013","-1013","1014","-1014","1015","-1015","1016","-1016","1017", _
    "-1017","1018","-1018","1019","-1019","102","-102","1020","-1020","1021", _
    "-1021","1022","-1022","1023","-1023","1024","-1024","1025","-1025","1026", _
    "-1026","1027","-1027","1028","-1028","1029","-1029","103","-103","1030", _
    "-1030","1031","-1031","1032","-1032","1033","-1033","1034","-1034","1035", _
    "-1035","1036","-1036","1037","-1037","1038","-1038","1039","-1039","104", _
    "-104","1040","-1040","1041","-1041","1042","-1042","1043","-1043","1044", _
    "-1044","1045","-1045","1046","-1046","1047","-1047","1048","-1048","1049", _
    "-1049","105","-105","1050","-1050","1051","-1051","1052","-1052","1053", _
    "-1053","1054","-1054","1055","-1055","1056","-1056","1057","-1057","1058", _
    "-1058","1059","-1059","106","-106","1060","-1060","1061","-1061","1062", _
    "-1062","1063","-1063","1064","-1064","1065","-1065","1066","-1066","1067", _
    "-1067","1068","-1068","1069","-1069","107","-107","1070","-1070","1071", _
    "-1071","1072","-1072","1073","-1073","1074","-1074","1075","-1075","1076", _
    "-1076","1077","-1077","1078","-1078","1079","-1079","108","-108","1080", _
    "-1080","1081","-1081","1082","-1082","1083","-1083","1084","-1084","1085", _
    "-1085","1086","-1086","1087","-1087","1088","-1088","1089","-1089","109", _
    "-109","1090","-1090","1091","-1091","1092","-1092","1093","-1093","1094", _
    "-1094","1095","-1095","1096","-1096","1097","-1097","1098","-1098","1099", _
    "-1099","11","-11","110","-110","1100","-1100","1101","-1101","1102","-1102", _
```

Comment: Maybe an helper column could solve this? Match data to your values you want to exclude, than filter that column on true or false.

Comment: Is there not a pattern to your numbers (other than using the `-` and `+` of the same) that you could perhaps generate in a formula/loop?

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I have tried running small loop formulas and  helper columns to solve this issue. Although they have been successful, they dramatically increase the processing time. Those tests were just trying to sort 250 numbers instead of the 8100 numbers that I need. The loops took over 45 minutes to complete, whereas the filter option completed in seconds. I may be wrong but seems as though any formula which addresses the problem by going down the column cell by cell creates a massive delay in time depending on the total number of rows.

Comment: Once the formula in the helper is in place, you want to either put calculations to manual or change cells to values instead of formulas. Otherwise its too heavey on your processing at it would involve array formulas (I assume)

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I have found what I am trying to do is not possible.

I opened a blank excel page and created a single row of numbers running from -4090 to 4095. I then saved it as a .csv file, open it with wordpad and used the Find/Replace function to replace all the commas (,) with a comma and space in quoatations (", "). This gave me all 8,191 numbers formatted as needed. I then copied the entire contents and pasted it into the macro's Autofilter array. Disaster ensued. Apparently, in addition to the 25 line limit for functions, there is an individual line-length limit of 1024 characters too. The copied numbers reached that 1024 limit, then wrapped around to the next lines. This continued until the all the numbers were pasted in. Unfortunately the line length limit was far exceeded - adding up to 66 lines, way over the 25 line limit. The whole function is red and invalid now.

Unless anyone has any other ideas, it looks like a loop or helper column may be the only options that will work.

Comment: Actually you should include all information that belong to your question into your original post. Answers are supposed to contain only solutions to the original questions (according to [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a helper column. Imagine the data looks like in column A in the image below:

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Example for your data that you want to filter in your worsheet `DataSheet`.</sup>*

Then put all the numbers you want to **exclude** from that data into another worksheet and name it `ExcludeList`.

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: Put all data to exclude into an ExcludeList (this way you can easily edit it without changing your VBA code).</sup>*

Then add a helper column in your data worksheet using the following formula

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A:A,ExcludeList!A:A,0),0)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

so that `A:A` points to your data you want to filter and `ExcludeList!A:A` points to the list of numbers you want to exclude. Now next to the data values you want to exclude there is a `TRUE` and next to the data you want to show there is a `FALSE`.

[image]
*<sup>Image 3: Add a helper column to your data that you can use for filtering.</sup>*

Now you can easily filter that helper column

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet").Columns("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="FALSE"
```

and all the data that should be excluded is invisible:

[image]
*<sup>Image 4: Filtered data without the values from your exclude list.</sup>*

Answer (score 0):

Again, thank you all for your suggestions, but after sleeping on it, I found a solution that is fast and works much better for my application.
I had gotten used to using the filter option from the home tab, and completely spaced out on the existance of the Advanced Filter option on the data tab! After doing a little research on the VBA code for this feature, I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
'Copies Column headings from "A9:O9" to "G1:U1"
    Range("A9:O9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G1:U1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Sets filter parameters for column "B" in Column "H"
    Range("H2").Value = "<-4095"
    Range("H3").Value = ">4095"
    Range("H4").Value = ">3"
    Range("H5").Value = "<1"
'Advanced Filter of data based on above parameter values for "B" column
    Range("A9:O" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("G1:U5"), Unique:=False
' Clears the parameter contents from cells "G1" thru "U5"
    Range("G1:U5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

My data starts in B9, so I was able to make use of blank cells G1 thru U5 for the temporary criteria range.
It works like a charm!